# Docker entry point not being found

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My docker image keeps returning the following error when I attempt to run it.

```
/bin/sh: 1: [python,: not found
```

Here is my dockerfile code

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y \
python3 \
python3-pip \
&& apt-get clean \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

    ENV INSTALL_PATH /docker-flowcell-restore
    RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH

    WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

    COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

   RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

   COPY src/ src/

   ENTRYPOINT ["python", "src/main.py"]
```

Here my project is my hierarchy

```
docker-flowcell-restore
    docker-flowcell-restore
        requirements.txt
        Dockerfile
        src
            __init__.py
            main.py
```

Thanks.

Comment: There surely is a typo in your Dockerfile.  Repository names must be lowercase.  `FROM Ubuntu` could not possibly build.

Comment: Yes. I was using a company repo and renamed for the sake of the post.

Comment: Single quotes are not valid json, so docker is trying to execute the json entrypoint as a string using a shell. Use double quotes instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed by adding

```
COPY /src/* $INSTALL_PATH/src/
ENTRYPOINT python3 src/main.py
```

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing ENTRYPOINT with the following one. (changing to " rather than ')

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "src/main.py"]
```

Comment: I tried this solution before as well. Still get the same error.

/bin/sh: 1: [“python”,: not found